# How do I correct my Node connection to MySQL with the hostname?

Tags: mysql, node.js, hostname

*** Edited the username from 'sabcozac@user' to 'sabcozac_user'

My connection to my hosted MySQL database fails because the hostname is inserted even though I don't include it anywhere. I read through the response here regarding [appending the hostname](https://serverfault.com/questions/149319/mysql-command-appends-localhost-to-username) but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

My `db.js` file doesn't contain the hostname but each time it gets inserted in my executable. I've provided both below and would appreciate any help anyone could offer please.

```
db.js
'user strict';

const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'cp14.domains.co.za',
  user     : 'sabcozac_user',
  port     : '3306',
  password : '************',
  database : 'sabcozac_fonebook'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

[image: Executable error screenshot]

I'm using a hosted database that is administered by PHPMyAdmin which doesn't allow me to add '@localhost' to the username.

Comment: maybe the @ symbol in the username is confusing it? It seems like a bug btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried the connection and it worked. I removed the other installation I had on the server (not the pre-installed PHPMyAdmin one) and this time the connection string didn't have the extra hostname in the user.

Now I have a 'Packet out of order' problem but I'll come back with a new question if needed.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` is part of the user definition and describes where the user is connecting from. You error message indicates you are connecting from a remote IP, so not localhost.

To create a user `CREATE USER sabcozac@'154.66.196.103' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`; Then give that user access to things with `GRANT ... TO sabcozac@'154.66.196.103'`

In your code you use the username without the `@hostname` component, so just `sabcozac`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation regarding the `localhost` bit. The trouble I have is the PHPMyAdmin SQL user doesn't have the rights to create users. When I create a user via the cPanel, it forces me to have 'sabcozac' + whatever else I want, meaning the username has to include that at least. The portion after the `_` is the unique part of any new user.

Comment: Further to this, I can establish a connection via SSH using MySQL Workbench if I use `sabcozac_user` because it doesn't append `@localhost`.

Comment: If you access via SSH to the actual DB server, then the user definition is `sabcozac_user@localhost`,  `sabcozac@'154.66.196.103'` is a different distinct user.